# ng add ngx-spinner : The package that you are trying to add does not support schematics

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular11, ngx-spinner

I'm new to Angular.

After executing `ng add ngx-spinner`, I encountered this error:

**The error ([ngx-spinner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner)):**

> The package that you are trying to add does not support schematics.
> You can try using a different version of the package or contact the
> package author to add ng-add support.

How can I solve this problem? (How can I add the module manually?)

[image: ng version]

[image: schematics]

Comment: Just use `npm install` to install the library. Then follow any docs the library has to use it.

Comment: @R.Richards: I did it but the problem is still not solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I uninstalled spinner with

```
npm uninstall ngx-spinner
```

and reinstalled with

```
npm install ngx-spinner --force
```

Now that's work well.

https://github.com/Napster2210/ngx-spinner/issues/163#issuecomment-768826528

Answer (score 0):

I had another version of '@angular/common', and I had to downgrade to a lower version and after to run the npm install ngx-spinner